# How to dynamically pass column names to a query?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql, dynamic-sql

Below is my problem and desired solution.

Query1:

```
Select colnames from table1;

Query1 Result:
 col1
 col2
 col3
 col4
```

Query2:

```
Select a1.* 
  from table2 a1;

-- should translate to
select a1.col1, a1.col2, a1.col3, a1.col4 from table2 a1;
```

My first query will give the list of column names,  I need to replace the .* with those column names in my second query.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this help? https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/native-dynamic-sql

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? SQL automatically expands the `.*` to include every column, why do you need to translate it into a different query? Are you trying to build something like `DBMS_UTILITY.EXPAND_SQL_TEXT`, and if so, why?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for dynamic SQL. The idea is to generate the query string from the results of a SQL query. You can then run it with `execute immediate`.

In your use case, that would look like:

```
declare
    p_sql varchar2(100);
begin
    select 
        'select ' 
        || listagg('a1.' || colnames, ', ') within group(order by colnames)
        || ' from table2 a1'
    into p_sql
    from table1;

    dbms_output.put_line('sql: ' || p_sql);  -- debug
    execute immediate p_sql;                 -- execute
end;
/
```

For your sample data, **[this generates](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a73c7df495126c46f77d346943ba298b)**:

```
dbms_output:
sql: select a1.col1, a1.col2, a1.col3, a1.col4 from table2 a1
```